# Talking batch AI (that learns) but I have one issue

Tags: batch-file, artificial-intelligence

When i use it, it will only speak when i teach it another word, i can't get it to speak a specific answer in the directory, do you guys have any opinions on how to go about fixing this, i'm stumped..

```
@ECHO OFF 
@mode con cols=55 lines=10
if not exist data.txt echo.>data.txt
:begin
set /p text="Talk: "
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=@" %%i in (data.txt) do (
if /i "%text%"=="%%i" (

 echo Visu: %%j
 goto begin
 )
 )
 :Learn
  echo --- I don't know that.
  set /p answer=--- What would be a good answer to '%text%'? 
echo %text%@%answer%>>data.txt
echo Visu: thank you
goto Aye

:Aye
echo set speech = Wscript.CreateObject("SAPI.spVoice") >> "temp.vbs"
echo speech.speak "%answer%" >> "temp.vbs"
start temp.vbs
pause
del temp.vbs
goto begin
```

Comment: Use `echo`s to debug and see what code is getting executed and why the code you're interested in is not. If you still can't fix it, give us more details about what you've tried.

Comment: iv literally tried everything except @LotPings fix. aha

Comment: so i just thought id take a chance and ask for help, and it worked better than i intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Make Aye a subroutine/function you can call with the text to speak.
- In a called sub the first argument is %1

---

```
@ECHO OFF 
mode con cols=55 lines=10
if not exist data.txt Type Nul >data.txt
:begin
cls& Echo Talk to Visu
set "text=" & set /p text="Talk: "
if not defined text exit /B
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=@" %%i in (data.txt
  ) do if /i "%text%"=="%%i" Call :Aye "%%~j" & Goto :begin 

:Learn
echo --- I don't know that.
echo --- What would be a good answer to '%text%'
set /p answer=?  
echo %text%@%answer%>>data.txt
Call :Aye "%answer%"
goto :begin

:Aye 
echo Visu: %~1
echo Visu: thank you
echo set speech = Wscript.CreateObject("SAPI.spVoice") > "temp.vbs"
echo speech.speak "%~1" >> "temp.vbs"
cscript //Nologo temp.vbs
Timeout /T 3 /Nobreak >Nul
del temp.vbs
goto :Eof
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

replace `start temp.vbs` with `cscript /nologo temp.vbs`.

And probably you want
`echo set speech = Wscript.CreateObject("SAPI.spVoice") > "temp.vbs"`
(`>` instead of `>>`) to overwrite the file every time?